# How to know what application/service is inserting records into a table

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way/method/tool to monitor or to know what application or service is inserting records into a table in ms sql?

Answer (score 2):

If you installed it as part of your SQL Client Tools installation, you can use the `SQL Server Profiler` tool to perform a trace of the activity taking place on a specific instance of SQL server. This includes capturing the actual sql batches which are inserting the data into your database.

When you setup the trace, select the `SQL:BatchStarting`(under the TSQL events) and `RPC:Starting` (under the Store Procedures) events. For each event select the following fields to be included in the trace:

- textdata - Will contain the actual query being executed. Look in here for your insert queries.
- spid
- starttime
- application name - Will contain the name of the application on the client if the client is configured with an application name
- ClientProcessID - Will contain the process ID of the client application calling SQL Server
- DatabaseID
- DatabaseName
- HostName - Will contain the name of the computer on which the client is running
- LoginName - Will contain the login of the user (either the SQL Server or WIndows login)

You can add a filter on either the `DatabaseID` or `DatabaseName` fields so the trace only returns events from the database you are interested in tracking down the inserts on.

Additionally, if have an idea about how the insert is being made (for instance a specific storee procedured being called to execute the insert) you can define a filter on the `textdata` field in the format of `%stored_procedure_name%` `%` symbols are wildcards and the text between them represents a porition of the query which is inserting the data.

Comment: I'm aware of the sql server profiler a little bit, but this needs to be ran manually and I'm worried about the processing overhead on the database server. Actually, I'm trying to debug an issue on the a database server and I want to know what application/s updates a particular table since I don't know what application/s performs the inserts on the table. Would running the sql profiler the whole day or half-day ok, meaning it won't be a considerable overhead?

Comment: The effect is going to depend on the current load on the DB server. Try a short test to see what effect profiler has on performance and also monitor the server with something like SCOM or newrelic while the trace is active so if there is a problem you know immediately. You can leave the profiler running for a day/half-day but if so you'll set it up to saves the results to a file and you'll want to enable the 'Server Processes trace data' so you don't get any skipped events. Also, the more exclude filters you can apply to the trace the better off you'll be trying to analyize the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you install Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, the "[Activity Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879320%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)" will apparently show you the process name of a given connection (and, e.g., what the last executed statement was).

Comment: Using the Activity Monitor, can the results be save to a file to be analyze later?

Comment: @Stanley: No idea, sorry. I haven't used it myself. MSDN has a [list of ways to monitor SQL server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191511.aspx), if it helps.